# EOFException when reading QueueFile tape

Tags: java, android, exception, square-tape

I'm using Square's [Tape](https://github.com/square/tape) library to queue uploads of data to the server.

The queue is stored in File in JSON format. When the app starts I init the queue and start uploading (i.e if on Wifi)  However on some devices on users I'm seeing `EOFException` with `'null'` message (logged in crashlytics).

The error occurs when creating a `FileObjectQueue` object from an existing file - from the debug info gather the actual file is ~1MB.

Any ideas what's causing this or how to prevent it? - maybe I need to dust up on my java.io.

**Edit: using Tape v1.2.1**

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:419)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:439)
at com.squareup.tape.QueueFile.readElement(:182)
at com.squareup.tape.QueueFile.readHeader(:162)
at com.squareup.tape.QueueFile.(:110)
at com.squareup.tape.FileObjectQueue.(:35)
at com.myapp.queue.MyUploadTaskQueue.create(:125)
```

**Updated** - Also seeing this error since upgrading to 1.2.2

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: File is corrupt; length stored in header is 0.
       at com.squareup.tape.QueueFile.readHeader(:165)
       at com.squareup.tape.QueueFile.<init>(:117)
       at com.squareup.tape.FileObjectQueue.<init>(:35)
```

Comment: What version of the library are you using?

Comment: Hey Jake, using Tape v1.2.1 (updated in question) but just checking the change log I see maybe a related fix "Prevent corruption when expanding a perfectly saturated queue" so gonna try 1.2.2. thx

Comment: Cool. That's exactly why I asked!

Comment: Hey @JakeWharton the 1.2.2 didn't seem to fix, still getting lots of EOFExceptions. I'm using a GSON converter as noted in Tape sample code. Do you think a different serialisation format help?

Comment: I'm getting the same `EOFException` on 1.2.2.  Did you ever find a resolution?

Comment: @RossHambrick No, I switched to using SQLite database where I had better visibility of the outbound queue and could for instance just remove the last enter if it had become corrupt.

Comment: I ended up solving this by making the ObjectQueue instance provided by Dagger a Singleton.  Which is probably my mistake and the right thing to do anyways.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet with using of FileObjectQueue?

Comment: The exception occurs when reading, not when creating.

Answer (score 1):

The EOFException shows that End Of File has been reached, that is, there are no more bytes to read. This exception is just another way to signal that there is nothing more to read, whereas other methods return a value, like -1. As you can see in your error stack trace, the methods throwing the exception are read methods; `java.io.RandomAccessFile.readFully(RandomAccessFile.java:419)` and `com.squareup.tape.QueueFile.readHeader(:165)`. As such, it can't be "prevented" unless you don't read all the bytes (which you typically want to), just catch it like so; `catch(EOFException e) { /* ignore */ }` :)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html

Comment: Generally yes, but the Square's API states that if the queue is empty the peek method will return null and not throw an exception. We might expect that the library will handle the EOF exception internally. So I don't believe that EOF exception is normal here.